# combine batch file with .exe file

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have an application "myprogram.exe"  that can only execute with the help of a command line in batch file this way :

```
myprogram.exe -p password123
```

if you click on the exe file without running the batch it'll display "Missed required command line option" 
I want to be able to run the .exe file without the need of clicking on the batch file (I don't mind having the batch file but I don't want to click on it to run the application)

or maybe if there is anyway to combine a batch file (.bat) and a .exe file together so when you open the exe file it runs ?

PS : I don't want to use any bat to exe softwares, because these softwares will drop the batch file on your temp folder and run it from there.

Comment: Edit the source code.

Comment: Why not simply create a shortcut that launches your executable with the command line parameters you need? That's not clicking on the batch file.

Comment: if you want to pass parameters, don't double click the exe file

Answer (score 2):

If you create a Shortcut to the executable, and then right-click on Shortcut icon and select Properties, you can edit the command and add the explicit options.
You may need to add double-quotes, to deal with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your soft without a .bat file just enter with this on your Command Prompt window:

`myprogram.exe -p password123`

Then press Enter.

This way you will not see the message "Missed required command line option".

Answer (score 1):

download "bat to exe" its a free software that will allow you to include the exe file and the bat file as an entry point into one .exe file thus allowing you to launch  the .exe file via bat by single click and from a single .exe  link to the freeware https://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter-Portable/3000-2069_4-10555897.html [interface of the s\w where to include the exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ34p.png)

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).